# clrscr()not working in VC++(VS 2008).....?

Tags: visual-c++

In VS 2008, I created an empty project in VC++ and added a source file as . . .

`

```
 #include<stdio.h>    

 #include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  ....
  clrscr();
  .....
  return 0;
}
```

`

**I get these errors/warnings :**

Warning 1 warning C4013: 'clrscr' undefined; assuming extern returning int c:\tc\toh.c 170 TOH

Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _clrscr referenced in function _main TOH.obj TOH

What the problem??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the FillConsoleOutputCharacter and FillConsoleOutputAttribute functions. There is even an example of how to do that at MSDN, convenniently called "[Clearing the screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682022(VS.85).aspx)"

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to mix Borland libraries with VC++?  That could be the problem.  Can you clear the console instead by sending a bunch of `\n`s?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that conio from c++ do not have the clrscr like the conio from c native lib!!

Alternatively, you can use system("cls") instead clrscr(). Its not the best solution, but in my case I was just testing an old program and trying to solve that problem was getting me angry!! lol

```
#define clrscr(); system("cls");
```

It will keep your code and automatically change all clrscr(). You can do one by one, if you want.

Maybe you also need to include stdlib if something goes wrong

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using clrscr(); use system("cls");