# Error Id returned 1 exit status and program.c:(.text+0xe):undefined reference to `clrscr'

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()

{
     int i;
     clrscr();
     printf("Enter the number to be displayed");
     scanf("%d",&i);
     printf("The entered number is %d",i);
     getch();
     }
```

I am able to run the above program in Turbo C++ but in Dev C++ I'm getting this error.

error:
[image]

Comment: (almost certainly) unrelated to your issue at hand, but also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: Turbo C++ is not a C++ compiler as it predate the first C++ standard (C++98) for almost a decade, therefore don't expect valid C++ code to be compiled in Turbo C++ and vice versa

Comment: @mayank you should write the error in the post, don't upload error or code's images.

Comment: But I'm getting this error in Dev C++....not in Turbo C++.

Comment: [clrscr()not working in VC++(VS 2008)…?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3646038/995714), [Why do I got error in clrscr(); it says undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41137638/995714), [Error with clrscr() on Dev C++ 5.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18766159/995714)

Comment: @MayankSingh dev C++ is an IDE, not a compiler. But it's likely using a standard C++ compiler (gcc) so it can't compile non-compliant Turbo C++ code like yours

Comment: @phuclv So what do i do to remove this error and get output like turbo c++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with clrscr() on Dev C++ 5.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766159/error-with-clrscr-on-dev-c-5-4-2)

Comment: You may get your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766159/error-with-clrscr-on-dev-c-5-4-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<conio.h>` is a non-standard header provided by Borland and a handful of other compilers and libc implementations. Dev C++ typically uses one of the Windows GCC ports, which don't provide any implementation of those functions.

If you want to use some sort of `clrscr` function in both you're going to have to come up with a more portable solution, because `<conio.h>` will not work with GCC.